# How can I obtain the time stamp from a file or directory in touch format?

Tags: date, stat, touch

According to many websites I found online the `touch` commands' `-t` argument accepts the time stamp in the following format:

```
[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]

Here,

CC: The first two digits of the year.
YY: The last two digits of the year.
MM: Month
DD: Day of the month
hh: Hour
mm: Minute
ss: Seconds
```

For example:

```
$ touch -t 199901011200 test.txt
```

Can I use the `date` or `stat` command to obtain the timestamp in the same format from a file or directory? By same format I mean the format above `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`
By default the `date` command has a different output.

Note: I do not want to use touch reference `-r` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `date` you specify the following format:

```bash
date -r test.txt +'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S'
```

1. `%Y`: Year (with four digits)
2. `%m`: Month number (with two digits)
3. `%d`: Day (with two digits)
4. `%H`: Hour (from 00 to 23)
5. `%M`: Minutes
6. `%S`: Seconds

You can check `man date` to more information.

Comment: Thank you. I think the `ss` in `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]` is different from what the `date` command's `%S` outputs because I get this error when I pipe the date ouput into touch: `touch: invalid date format ‘20220901123513’`. I'm wondering if `touch` uses the seconds since the epoch which is `%s` in date. That works. I'm just not sure what they mean in `[.ss]`

Comment: @ZoltanKing I've updated the answer. With touch you should add a `.` before the seconds.